# Cannot access Angular Input variables without using "set"

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new to Angular I am having trouble understanding what is going on here. I have two components, A and B, and I wish to pass some data from A to B. In component A I have code as follows:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-a',
  template: `<comp-b [var_x]="var_x"></comp-b>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  // Info to send to Component B
  var_x: any = 'something'
}
```

Then in component B, I have something like:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-b',
  template: `Info from Component A: {{var_x}}`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() var_x: any;
}
```

The problem is, that code does not work. I am not able to see the value of `var_x`. I get `undefined`. However, when I substitute `$Input()` for the code below, I can get the value of `var_x`.

```
var_x: any;

@Input() set var_x(_var_x: any) {
    this.var_x = _var_x;
}
```

I have scratched my head as to why it's like this. All my imports seem fine. I can not for the life of me figure what's wrong and I hope someone out there can help me out. Thanks guys!

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: I am trying to figure out why it does not work when I just use Input() without "set"

Comment: @ritaj sorry! I have edited the question. Thanks for the point out.

Comment: This worked for me. what is the issue? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddsanv

Answer (score 0):

What are errors in angular CLI, also, your component selector must be inside single quotation marks like : selector: 'comp-b', what you have is selector: comp-b'

Comment: Ah, yes. It was a typo in the question. Fixed it. It's strange that I do not get any errors in my angular CLI. Just a `console.log(var_x)` in my code which gives `undefined`. Really strange this.